# Push to a New Array a Sequential Subset of an Existing Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have a certain sequential number of items within an array (say from index 0 - 31) that I want to push to a new array, how can I do that? Basically I want some logic that says, take items with an index of 0 - 31, and push them to a new array.

I know how to get the index when I know the string value, such as this:

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
let a = fruits.indexOf("Apple"); // will be 2
```

.., but how do I push to a new array a subset of indexed items, like from 0 - 31, as I mentioned.

Comment: what is desired output ?

Comment: A new array with the contents of all the items of the original array that had an index from 0 - 31 -- so the first 31 items in the original array.

Comment: Are you looking to splice? `var months = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
months.splice(1, 0, 'Feb');
// inserts at index 1`

Comment: @Ademo so you want to copy the array?

Comment: I want a copy of the subset of the array. It's been pointed out that I can do this with `slice()`, since that allows me to specify the beginning and ending index to include -- which is exactly what I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)? It will return a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from the start to end index.

For example:

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
console.log(fruits.slice(1, 3)) // logs: ["Orange", "Apple"]
```

Comment: Ah, right. Yes, of course, with slice() we can specify the beginning and ending indexes. Thanks, @skovy!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to select the range of items that you want, where the second parameter is the index.

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

const getRange = (arr, start, end) => arr.filter((itm, idx) => idx >= start && idx <= end)

console.log(getRange(fruits, 2, 3))
console.log(getRange(fruits, 0, 2))
```

Comment: Interesting. Didn't realize you could use filter() like this.